# Struggling to center my Font Awesome Icons

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I am having trouble centering my font-awesome icons and my buttons.  I tried doing in through a through my CSS folder and I also tried inline styling as well. I have them both in my example below.  Can somebody tell me why it is not centering and what would be the best approach to fixing this?

https://jsfiddle.net/silosc/0emaydqn/11/

```
Here is my HTML folder:
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="report-card-sm">
    <h2>
       We're sorry, this page is under construction.
    </h2>
    <p>We reccomend you try the following:</p>
    <ul class="fa-ul">
        <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="align-content: center "></i></span>Checking your date range and readjust it</li>
        <li><span class="fa-li"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="align-content: center "></i></span>Importing your file by clicking on the Upload Data button</li>

    </ul>
    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Go Back</button>
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Upload Data</button>
</div>
```

This is my CSS folder:

```
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

ul i {

  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  justify-contern: center;
}
```

Comment: I want to center the icon with the text.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the `<span>` tag from the li and use font-awesome directly in `<i>` tag. I have also added some padding to the `<i>` tag or **fa** icon so that it doesn't collapse with the `<li>` text.

For centering the `buttons` simply add those in a `div` and give property to that `div` `text-align:center;`

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

ul li .fa{
padding-right:5px;
}


.center-div{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="report-card-sm">
    <h2>
       We're sorry, this page is under construction.
    </h2>
    <p>We reccomend you try the following:</p>
    <ul class="fa-ul">
        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Checking your date range and readjust it</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Importing your file by clicking on the Upload Data button</li>
        
    </ul>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div class="center-div">
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Go Back</button>
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Upload Data</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

`fa-li` class cause the problem. Because it contains the CSS of being an absolute element. You can simply remove the `fa-li` class from the `span` tags. To maintain a space you can add padding or margin values. Below snippet can help you.

To centre the buttons I have wrapped the buttons with a `div` which is initially a block element. By adding `text-align:center` CSS to the `div`(block) element, it centers the children(`buttons`).

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

ul i {
  justify-content: center;
}

button {
  justify-contern: center;
}

ul li>span {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn-wrapper{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="report-card-sm">
  <h2>
    We're sorry, this page is under construction.
  </h2>
  <p>We reccomend you try the following:</p>
  <ul class="fa-ul">
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="align-content: center "></i></span>Checking your date range and readjust it</li>
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="align-content: center "></i></span>Importing your file by clicking on the Upload Data button</li>
  </ul>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Go Back</button>
  <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Upload Data</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please notice that this solution does not center the buttons "centering my font-awesome icons and my buttons"

Comment: @dennisvandehoef Sorry, my bad. I have updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1):

Try with flexbox:

```
ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

CSS:

```
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

ul{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
}
```

Use `<center>` tag in HTML 4.01:

```
<center>
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Go Back</button>
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Upload Data</button>
</center>
```

In HTML5: you will need to group buttons in a div and use `text-align: center`

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Go Back</button>
    <button class="btn-orange fa-orange">Upload Data</button>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3xkof2e/)

Comment: please notice that this solution does not center the buttons "centering my font-awesome icons and my buttons"

Answer (score 0):

You should put `text-align: center;` on the parent elements (create one ?).

And create a new class for `<span class="fa-li">` to unset `position: absolute;` and maybe set a `margin-right` to unstick icon and text

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue while working with a django project. All I did was to include the html doctype tag  and my icons were back in center.

You might want to try it out